# Php, exception, is there a path which not covered?

Tags: php, exception

hard to describe, given this example?

```
public function x()
{
    try
    {
        operation();
        return true;
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    can this reach this line???
}
```

so is there a way that neither return true nor false will run? Somehow. Anyhow.

Comment: No you can't reach that line as you are returning either true or false in the try / catch statement. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you want to reach on that line, don't return value in `try catch`.

Comment: What you dont want it?

Comment: I added an explanation

Answer (score 1):

You should not be able to reach the specified line.

Have you come across a case where this is happening? If so, provide some code and we can tell you why/how it is happening. If not, then your answer is no.

Answer (score -1):

explanation: I was just affraid maybe there is some kind of side effect, or something. Imagine that line:

```
function a()
{
    if (rand(0,1))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    *************
}
```

check the stars. I know its 100% that they wont be reached - still they are there, and theoretically the construction allows that :))

if I rewrite like this:

```
function a()
{
    if (rand(0,1))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

then its 101% Im sure that it wont run any uncovered block

Comment: `if (true) {return true;}` will always be executed, so it really doesn't matter what you write after. What does mean this part: "Im sure that it wont run any uncovered block"? What wont run which block?